# Elasticsearch allow wildcard in term

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to implement wildcard terms in my project but in different direction.
So how it should work. Customer create new item and says this should be visible if user search for **car**, **cars**, **new car**, **fast car**, **new car in my house**. It would be easy for instance if we always know that atleast one term should match, but the problem that some times only one term should match, some times there could be more. So could be that it should match only if user search for **new car**, **in my house there is new car**. That is why we think about possibility to allow customer to define %car% this will match anything where is car, or %new car% this should match only if there is two terms in search query

For instance i will index document

```
{
"name": "title",
"terms": ["term1", "multiple*", "*between*"]
}
```

So now if user search for **term1**, **multipleword**, **multiple terms**, **something between terms** i should found this document.

One of my ideas could using script query and try to match terms to search term, but i am not sure about performance

NOTE. I will have around 100 documents like that where i would need to such kind of search

Comment: Hm, this sounds more like [percolator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-percolate.html) usage. Have you checked this one out to see if it fits better with what you need?

Comment: Following up on the idea of percolator, you define 100 queries that should match those 100 documents you say you'll have. Those queries will be wildcard queries. Then when your users search, they will present the terms to search as a normal document: `{"words":["term1", "multipleword", "multiple terms", "something between terms"]}` but instead of sending it to `_search` it will be sent to `_percolate`.

Comment: The problem is that i dont know which terms will be they are totally dynamic. Customer deside wildcards and the other user will search something.

Comment: So, your customer defines a list of terms as a document. With percolator, they will define that list of terms as a query. Of course, you need an intermediate layer in your application (if there is one), where you build the percolator query. And instead of indexing the document, you index the percolator query. A more important question: your docs have `name` and `terms`. Is there anything else other than these two fields in them?

Comment: Yes there are but they are not searchable, there is ID, Html

Comment: If you only have 100 documents it's probably going to be easier just to pull them all down, iterate through in memory and do regular expression matches on the search terms... no need for a smart solution when a dumb one works.

Comment: That is why i am thinking about using script, query even more it will be cched so it should be supper fast

Comment: The easiest way to decide whether something will perform is to implement it and see if it performs :)

Comment: If you are using script to do the actual matching, then what's the point of using Elasticsearch? You are basically doing the search in Groovy.

Comment: @AndreiStefan This feature is not yet implemented and i posted question to see if there is any options besides script. I will read about percolator, but as i see it will not fit in this solution

Comment: @AndreiStefan in addition even if iwill be using script it will still be cached in ES. And there will be two 2 first query will be regular match of terms, second will be this kind of wildcard match, so at least one should match